# Failed to push to remote repository. Not a valid reference

Tags: git, visual-studio

I would like to push the testbranch to remote but unable to do so.

[image]

The output window says

```
 Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Not a valid reference 'origin/develop'
```

I think I may have merged the testbranch from local develop initially.

Comment: What command did you try using?

Comment: Rightclicked the testbranch and selected Push

Comment: as the error indicates: `See the Output window for more details`. Go to the output window and check the error. CTRL + ALT + O to toggle the Output window

Comment: @ztadic91 Please read my question completely. I have pasted what was there in the output window.

Comment: oops, my bad. I was thinking more information would be available.